# EFCore.BulkExtensions context does not contain a definition for BulkInsert

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I installed EntityFramework 6.2.0 , EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.5 and EFCore.BulkExtensions 3.1.5. EFCore.BulkExtensions package I installed from nuget is this: https://github.com/borisdj/EFCore.BulkExtensions

context.BulkInsert(entities, bulkConfig); gives me an error "context does not contain a definition for BulkInsert .."

Answer (score 0):

Try remove EntityFramework 6.2.0 and then Try this:

```
var context = new DbContext(options); // or you can register your dbContext in Startup
context.BulkInsert<object>(yourObjects);
```

Comment: when I remove ef 6.2.0 my db first codes gives error as expected

Comment: You cannot use EntityFramework 6 in .net core project. And bulk extensions are just for entityframework-core.